# How do I prevent program misinterpreting input in pygame?

Tags: python, input, pygame, logic

I am making a simple Tic Tac Toe game in pygame for my school project. I managed to put together some code (sorry if it is a bit messy, it is probably the left-overs of the code that I tried to use to fix my current issue), that in a way works as expected. I did however encounter a weird bug, I am not sure why, but it seems like my program is not able to handle rapid user input (if a user clicks quite fast), and instead of putting a circle then a cross it might put 2 circles or 2 crosses. If the user goes quite slowly it works fine, but I am looking for a way to get rid of this issue, if anyone could hint me towards something I would be really thankful. Here is the sourcecode:

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

DISPLAY_WIDTH = 400
DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 400
BOX_SIZE = 50
BOARD_WIDTH = 3
BOARD_HEIGHT = 3


BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255,   0,   0)
BACKGROUND_COLOR = (198, 187, 133)
indexList = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "b3", "c1", "c2", "c3"]

gameFinished = False


def game_loop():
    global DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT, displaySurface, gameFinished

    pygame.init()
    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()

    displaySurface = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Tic Tac Toe")
    displaySurface.fill(BACKGROUND_COLOR)
    pygame.draw.line(displaySurface, BLACK, (140, 20), (140, 380), 10)
    pygame.draw.line(displaySurface, BLACK, (260, 20), (260, 380), 10)
    pygame.draw.line(displaySurface, BLACK, (20, 140), (380, 140), 10)
    pygame.draw.line(displaySurface, BLACK, (20, 260), (380, 260), 10)
    box1 = pygame.Rect(20, 20, 120, 120)
    box2 = pygame.Rect(140, 20, 120,120)
    box3 = pygame.Rect(260, 20, 120, 120)
    box4 = pygame.Rect(20, 140, 120, 120)
    box5 = pygame.Rect(140, 140, 120, 120)
    box6 = pygame.Rect(260, 140, 120, 120)
    box7 = pygame.Rect(20, 260, 120, 120)
    box8 = pygame.Rect(140, 260, 120, 120)
    box9 = pygame.Rect(260, 260, 120, 120)
    circle = pygame.image.load("circle.png")
    cross = pygame.image.load("cross.png")
    boardBoxes = [box1, box2, box3,  box4, box5, box6, box7, box8, box9]
    mouseY = 0
    mouseX = 0
    placesTaken = {0: False, 1: False, 2: False, 3: False, 4: False, 5: False, 6: False, 7: False, 8: False}

    turn = 1
    board = generate_boxes(0)
    print(repr(board))

    while not gameFinished:
        mouseClick = False
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                mouseX, mouseY = event.pos
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                mouseClick = True
                mouseX, mouseY = event.pos
            if mouseClick is True and turn == 1:
                get_mouse_overbox(mouseX, mouseY, boardBoxes, turn, board)
                print("Player")
                turn += 1
            elif mouseClick is True and turn == 2:
                get_mouse_overbox(mouseX, mouseY, boardBoxes, turn, board)
                turn -= 1

        if board[0] == 1 and placesTaken[0] is False:
            put_image(circle, 20, 20)
            placesTaken[0] = True
        elif board[0] == 2 and placesTaken[0] is False:
            put_image(cross, 20, 20)
            placesTaken[0] = True
        if board[1] == 1 and placesTaken[1] is False:
            put_image(circle, 140, 20)
            placesTaken[1] = True
        elif board[1] == 2 and placesTaken[1] is False:
            put_image(cross, 140, 20)
            placesTaken[1] = True
        if board[2] == 1 and placesTaken[2] is False:
            put_image(circle, 260, 20)
            placesTaken[2] = True
        elif board[2] == 2 and placesTaken[2] is False:
            put_image(cross, 260, 20)
            placesTaken[2] = True
        if board[3] == 1 and placesTaken[3] is False:
            put_image(circle, 20, 140)
            placesTaken[3] = True
        elif board[3] == 2 and placesTaken[3] is False:
            put_image(cross, 20, 140)
            placesTaken[3] = True
        if board[4] == 1 and placesTaken[4] is False:
            put_image(circle, 140, 140)
            placesTaken[4] = True
        elif board[4] == 2 and placesTaken[4] is False:
            put_image(cross, 140, 140)
            placesTaken[4] = True
        if board[5] == 1 and placesTaken[5] is False:
            put_image(circle, 260, 140)
            placesTaken[5] = True
        elif board[5] == 2 and placesTaken[5] is False:
            put_image(cross, 260, 140)
            placesTaken[5] = True
        if board[6] == 1 and placesTaken[6] is False:
            put_image(circle, 20, 260)
            placesTaken[6] = True
        elif board[6] == 2 and placesTaken[6] is False:
            put_image(cross, 20, 260)
            placesTaken[6] = True
        if board[7] == 1 and placesTaken[7] is False:
            put_image(circle, 140, 260)
            placesTaken[7] = True
        elif board[7] == 2 and placesTaken[7] is False:
            put_image(cross, 140, 260)
            placesTaken[7] = True
        if board[8] == 1 and placesTaken[8] is False:
            put_image(circle, 260, 260)
            placesTaken[8] = True
        elif board[8] == 2 and placesTaken[8] is False:
            put_image(cross, 260, 260)
            placesTaken[8] = True

        FPSCLOCK.tick(60)
        pygame.display.update()


def put_image(image_name, x_cord, y_cord):
    global displaySurface
    displaySurface.blit(image_name, (x_cord, y_cord))


def generate_boxes(value):
    boxesFilled = []
    for i in range(9):
        boxesFilled.append(value)
    return boxesFilled


def board_getcircles(board):
    onlyCircleBoard = [0 if i == 2 else i for i in board]
    return onlyCircleBoard


def board_getcrosses(board):
    onlyCrossBoard = [0 if i == 2 else i for i in board]
    return onlyCrossBoard


def get_mouse_overbox(mouse_x, mouse_y, box_list, which_turn, boardlist):
    if which_turn == 1:
        for counter in range(len(box_list)):
            if box_list[counter].collidepoint(mouse_x, mouse_y):
                boardlist[counter] = 1
    elif which_turn == 2:
        for caunter in range(len(box_list)):
            if box_list[caunter].collidepoint(mouse_x, mouse_y):
                boardlist[caunter] = 2

game_loop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pygame.event.get](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) will retrieve all events that are in the queue so you can have multiple updates that get rendered all at once. Because you don't check whose turn it is when filling in the images you have the possibility of filling in more than one cross or circle at a time.

Why this happens:

```
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            mouseClick = True
            mouseX, mouseY = event.pos
```

In the loop `mouseClick` gets set as `True` the first time around, but because you have more than one event in the queue event.get() has another element to process and this time it runs the loop again with `mouseclick` is True. But this time we are still in the loop because `event.get()` is a list more than one, so:

```
        elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
            mouseX, mouseY = event.pos
```

Now this executes, but `mouseClick` is erroneously `True` here when processing this so we fall into the other statement again which is not what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone would be interested in finding the answer or just has a similar problem here is the code after I changed it (it works now, thanks for the answer shuttle87)

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

DISPLAY_WIDTH = 400
DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 400
BOX_SIZE = 50
BOARD_WIDTH = 3
BOARD_HEIGHT = 3


BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255,   0,   0)
BACKGROUND_COLOR = (198, 187, 133)
indexList = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "b3", "c1", "c2", "c3"]

gameFinished = False


def game_loop():
    global DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT, displaySurface, gameFinished

    pygame.init()
    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()

    displaySurface = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Tic Tac Toe")
    displaySurface.fill(BACKGROUND_COLOR)
    pygame.draw.line(displaySurface, BLACK, (140, 20), (140, 380), 10)
    pygame.draw.line(displaySurface, BLACK, (260, 20), (260, 380), 10)
    pygame.draw.line(displaySurface, BLACK, (20, 140), (380, 140), 10)
    pygame.draw.line(displaySurface, BLACK, (20, 260), (380, 260), 10)
    box1 = pygame.Rect(20, 20, 120, 120)
    box2 = pygame.Rect(140, 20, 120,120)
    box3 = pygame.Rect(260, 20, 120, 120)
    box4 = pygame.Rect(20, 140, 120, 120)
    box5 = pygame.Rect(140, 140, 120, 120)
    box6 = pygame.Rect(260, 140, 120, 120)
    box7 = pygame.Rect(20, 260, 120, 120)
    box8 = pygame.Rect(140, 260, 120, 120)
    box9 = pygame.Rect(260, 260, 120, 120)
    circle = pygame.image.load("circle.png")
    cross = pygame.image.load("cross.png")
    boardBoxes = [box1, box2, box3,  box4, box5, box6, box7, box8, box9]
    mouseY = 0
    mouseX = 0
    placesTaken = {0: False, 1: False, 2: False, 3: False, 4: False, 5: False, 6: False, 7: False, 8: False}

    turn = 1
    board = generate_boxes(0)
    print(repr(board))

    while not gameFinished:
        moveDone = False
        mouseClick = False






        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                mouseClick = True
                mouseX, mouseY = event.pos
            if mouseClick is True and turn == 1 and moveDone == False:
                get_mouse_overbox(mouseX, mouseY, boardBoxes, turn, board)
                print("Player1")
                moveDone = True
            elif mouseClick is True and turn == 2 and moveDone == False:
                get_mouse_overbox(mouseX, mouseY, boardBoxes, turn, board)
                print("Player2")
                moveDone = True

            if board[0] == 1 and placesTaken[0] is False:
                put_image(circle, 20, 20)
                placesTaken[0] = True
                turn += 1
            elif board[0] == 2 and placesTaken[0] is False:
                put_image(cross, 20, 20)
                placesTaken[0] = True
                turn -= 1
            if board[1] == 1 and placesTaken[1] is False:
                put_image(circle, 140, 20)
                placesTaken[1] = True
                turn += 1
            elif board[1] == 2 and placesTaken[1] is False:
                put_image(cross, 140, 20)
                placesTaken[1] = True
                turn -= 1
            if board[2] == 1 and placesTaken[2] is False:
                put_image(circle, 260, 20)
                placesTaken[2] = True
                turn += 1
            elif board[2] == 2 and placesTaken[2] is False:
                put_image(cross, 260, 20)
                placesTaken[2] = True
                turn -= 1
            if board[3] == 1 and placesTaken[3] is False:
                put_image(circle, 20, 140)
                placesTaken[3] = True
                turn += 1
            elif board[3] == 2 and placesTaken[3] is False:
                put_image(cross, 20, 140)
                placesTaken[3] = True
                turn -= 1
            if board[4] == 1 and placesTaken[4] is False:
                put_image(circle, 140, 140)
                placesTaken[4] = True
                turn += 1
            elif board[4] == 2 and placesTaken[4] is False:
                put_image(cross, 140, 140)
                placesTaken[4] = True
                turn -= 1
            if board[5] == 1 and placesTaken[5] is False:
                put_image(circle, 260, 140)
                placesTaken[5] = True
                turn += 1
            elif board[5] == 2 and placesTaken[5] is False:
                put_image(cross, 260, 140)
                placesTaken[5] = True
                turn -= 1
            if board[6] == 1 and placesTaken[6] is False:
                put_image(circle, 20, 260)
                placesTaken[6] = True
                turn += 1
            elif board[6] == 2 and placesTaken[6] is False:
                put_image(cross, 20, 260)
                placesTaken[6] = True
                turn -= 1
            if board[7] == 1 and placesTaken[7] is False:
                put_image(circle, 140, 260)
                placesTaken[7] = True
                turn += 1
            elif board[7] == 2 and placesTaken[7] is False:
                put_image(cross, 140, 260)
                placesTaken[7] = True
                turn -= 1
            if board[8] == 1 and placesTaken[8] is False:
                put_image(circle, 260, 260)
                placesTaken[8] = True
                turn += 1
            elif board[8] == 2 and placesTaken[8] is False:
                put_image(cross, 260, 260)
                placesTaken[8] = True
                turn -= 1


        FPSCLOCK.tick(60)
        pygame.display.update()


def get_mouse_overbox(mouse_x, mouse_y, box_list, which_turn, boardlist):
    if which_turn == 1:
        for counter in range(len(box_list)):
            if box_list[counter].collidepoint(mouse_x, mouse_y) and which_turn == 1:
                boardlist[counter] = 1
    elif which_turn == 2:
        for caunter in range(len(box_list)):
            if box_list[caunter].collidepoint(mouse_x, mouse_y) and which_turn == 2:
                boardlist[caunter] = 2


def put_image(image_name, x_cord, y_cord):
    global displaySurface
    displaySurface.blit(image_name, (x_cord, y_cord))


def generate_boxes(value):
    boxesFilled = []
    for i in range(9):
        boxesFilled.append(value)
    return boxesFilled


def board_getcircles(board):
    onlyCircleBoard = [0 if i == 2 else i for i in board]
    return onlyCircleBoard


def board_getcrosses(board):
    onlyCrossBoard = [0 if i == 2 else i for i in board]
    return onlyCrossBoard




game_loop()
```

As a short summary of what I've done I moved the mass of if sentences into the for event in loop, and made it so that turn increases or decreases by 1 when the picture actually placed on the table instead of doing it when a player clicks. Another thing I've done is I have added a moveDone variable which tracks whether the the function that changes the state of the board (get_mouse_overbox) was already initiated in the current loop. Hope this helps someone and again thanks for the help shuttle87